# Does Python underallocate memory for tuples?

Tags: python, memory-management

OK, the mistake is almost certainly mine and not Python's, but I came across some code that can be used to show how much memory has been allocated for various variables and saw a puzzling result. The code is as follows:

```
import sys

def show_sizeof(x, level=0):

    print "\t" * level, x.__class__, sys.getsizeof(x), x

    if hasattr(x, '__iter__'):
        if hasattr(x, 'items'):
            for xx in x.items():
                show_sizeof(xx, level + 1)
        else:
            for xx in x:
                show_sizeof(xx, level + 1)
```

It seems to take a variable and then return its class, amount of memory allocated for it and its value. If the object is an iterable, this methos recursively calls itself on all the members of that iterable.

Now when I try this (on my 64-bit machine):

```
>>> show_sizeof(('a', 213))
 <type 'tuple'> 72 ('a', 213)
    <type 'str'> 38 a
    <type 'int'> 24 213
```

I see that 72 bytes have been allocated for my tuple and only 62 (= 38 + 24) are used. This makes sense. However, when I add another element to my tuple, I see this:

```
>>> show_sizeof(('a', 213, 1))
<type 'tuple'> 80 ('a', 213, 1)
     <type 'str'> 38 a
     <type 'int'> 24 213
     <type 'int'> 24 1
```

The tuple uses 80 bytes, but its members seem to require 86 bytes (= 38 + 24 + 24). Shouldn't the tuple need at *least* 86 bytes???

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are misunderstanding the output. `sys.getsizeof()` only reports memory use for the object itself, never for any objects that it references.

The tuple object consists of *pointers to other objects*. The whole tuple, including those pointers, takes up 72 bytes. That those pointer are references to objects that also take up memory is neither here nor there, those objects *themselves* are not part of the memory footprint of the tuple.

Note that Python can re-use references. There is only ever *one* copy of the `None` object, for example, but the `(None, None)` tuple still needs to record two references to that one object. That tuple still requires 72 bytes of memory:

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.getsizeof((None, None))
72
>>> sys.getsizeof(None)
16
```

The total memory required for the `(None, None)` tuple is 72 + 16 bytes. Other containers can reference the `None` object, but those objects don't have to include those 16 bytes, only the memory space to hold enough pointers.